# Portable Python Not Starting Script

Tags: python, portability

Noob question.

I'm trying out Portable Python, but I can't get it to load a script from the Python-Portable.exe executable. I'm running from command line:

```
> Python-Portable.exe hello.py
```

To get it to load hello.py, which I put at the same level as the exectuable and just in case, in the same level as the real python.exe executable. It starts Portable Python, shows a splash screen for a second, then shows a console window and immediately closes it.

However, if I use command line to start python.exe directly, passing it hello.py it works correctly. Two questions then -

Why doesn't it work using Python-Portable.exe?

What'd the difference between starting Python-Portable.exe and starting Python.exe directly?

EDIT: Here is hello.py, its the example used on the Portable Python website.

```
print("Hello world")

a = True
if a == True:
    print("It is true!")
else:
    print("It is false...")

b = raw_input("Enter value:")
print("Your value is")
print(b)

raw_input("Press enter to continue...")
```

Comment: What is the content of hello.py? If it's a simple `print("Hello, world!")` then when the script finishes the portable-python process will end. If you add a line `input()` at the end of your hello.py the script will wait for input (upon receipt of which it will finish), and might have the behaviour you're expecting?

Comment: I take your point, but it's not that. I've included the code for hello.py. It behaves exactly as expected when run directly through Python.exe.

Comment: Understood - just checking :) Next debug question - which version of Python is your Python-Portable using? There's no raw_input() in Python3 - that call would cause a `NameError` which could crash your script and close your window. What happens if you replace calls to `raw_input` with calls to `input` instead?

Comment: It's running Py 2.7, so the code should be gravvy. As I said, running it directly with python.exe is fine, but PortablePython.exe (I assume it simply acts as a buffer to python.exe) doesn't do anything with it.

If I run PortablePython.exe with giving it a commandline parameter, it loads up the interactive interpreter just fine.

Comment: Ahh I'm an idiot, there was a bad line of code stopping it run and it doesn't give error output it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in hello.py.

Bad code is not run, and you don't get any feedback.

Comment: Next time copy paste _your_ code, and not the code from the example page - it's very hard to debug code you can't see ;)

Comment: I made two copies of hello.py, just in case the working path was lower down in the python.exe folder. When I ran it directly with python.exe, it was running a different version of hello.py (correct version). The broken version had while(1) with no colon or code after.

Even so, two copies of the same thing is rarely a good idea.